# Did not or had not. Which one to use?

Tags: grammar

> He once conducted a party, but he **did not** invite me/**had not** invited
>   me.

To me,
Did not invite sounds like present case. So i guess it'd be 
Had not invited

Comment: Present case would be "does not invite me" or "is not inviting me".

Answer (score 2):

*Did* is the simple past of the verb *to do*. Present tense would be "he does not invite me."  So it is correct when talking about a past event to say, "he did not invite me," since it's the *did* that makes it past tense.  When you have an auxillary verb like the *did* in this sentence, than it's the one that gets conjugated, and the other verb (*invite*) is just a bare infinitive that stays unchanged regardless of tense or subject/verb agreement.

Using *had not* (past perfect) is not necessarily wrong, but I'd only do it if I wanted to emphasize that the lack of invitation was something that happened before the event that I really wanted to be the point of my story.

For example:

> He once hosted a party, but he had not invited me. I showed up anyway.

This emphasizes that the point of my story is my showing up at the party, which is expressed in the simple past.  The host's decision to not invite me is something that happened even farther back in the past, and is in the past perfect.

(Note that I agree with the other responder that "conducted" is not a good choice of words for a party.)

Comment: Is it correct.   He once hosted a party but he didn't invite me?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I'd probably put a comma after _party_ though.

Comment: They're both correct. You could say "he did not invite me" or "he had not invited me" in that situation. In this instance, either one would work, but that's not always the case. The latter one shows that the want of invitation *had* occurred before he hosted the party.

Answer (score 0):

The verb you are referencing is *invite*, not *conducted* (by the way, I would use *threw* or *hosted* instead of conducted, which is never used in reference to a party), so the proper form would be *did not* invite.